# Jquery or Javascript create ranking column based from total

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to compute and fill the ranking in the image below based on the total. How will be able to achieve this using js/jquery?.

I have created the table manually (dynamically also) using HTML. I also have button to generate the rank (which I know how to do it). I just want to have a function or way to add rank to my column.

So that rank should be in order (1, 2, 2, 3).

```
<table id="table" class="table table-stripe table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="d-none">ID</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Crit1</td>
                            <td>Crit2</td>
                            <td>Crit3</td>
                            <td>Crit4</td>
                            <td>Crit5</td>
                            <td>Total</td>
                            <td>Rank</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                <td class="d-none">2</td>
                                <td>aaaa</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>50</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td class="total"></td>
                                <td class="Rank"></td>

                            </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                <td class="d-none">3</td>
                                <td>Greggggg</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="total"></td>
                                <td class="Rank"></td>

                            </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                <td class="d-none">4</td>
                                <td>Jjjjoohhn</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="total"></td>
                                <td class="Rank"></td>

                            </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                <td class="d-none">5</td>
                                <td>asdada</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="total"></td>
                                <td class="Rank"></td>

                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                </table>
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show your HTML and js code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to organise the total score by getting all the values, sort and remove duplicates.

And you can assign the rank value by `$('.total').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == v;}).next().text(i + 1);`

You can do something like:

```js
$(function() {
  //Get all total values, sort and remove duplicates
  let totalList = $(".total")
    .map(function() {return $(this).text()})
    .get()
    .sort(function(a,b){return a - b })
    .reduce(function(a, b) {if (b != a[0]) a.unshift(b);return a}, [])

  //Assign rank
  totalList.forEach((v, i) => {
    $('.total').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == v;}).next().text(i + 1);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-stripe table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-none">ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Crit1</td>
      <td>Crit2</td>
      <td>Crit3</td>
      <td>Crit4</td>
      <td>Crit5</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>Rank</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-none">2</td>
      <td>aaaa</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="total">80</td>
      <td class="Rank"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-none">3</td>
      <td>Greggggg</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total">65</td>
      <td class="Rank"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-none">4</td>
      <td>Jjjjoohhn</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total">65</td>
      <td class="Rank"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-none">5</td>
      <td>asdada</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="total">50</td>
      <td class="Rank"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

You can even make it shorter like

```
$(".total")
    .map(function(){return $(this).text()})
    .get()
    .sort(function(a,b){return a - b })
    .reduce(function(a, b){ if (b != a[0]) a.unshift(b); return a }, [])
    .forEach((v,i)=>{
        $('.total').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == v;}).next().text(i + 1);
    });
```

Comment: I got the rank in reverse order. so i use reverse()  ..............                    
  .sort(function(a,b){return a - b }).reverse()